# WCF Multiple channels for one service instance

Tags: c#, wcf, servicehost

This is my code for server application:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFirst
{
    [OperationContract]
    void First();
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface ISecond
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Second();
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
class Service : IFirst, ISecond
{
    static int count = 0;
    int serviceID;

    public Service()
    {
        serviceID = ++count;

        Console.WriteLine("Service {0} created.", serviceID);
    }

    public void First()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("First function. ServiceID: {0}", serviceID);
    }

    public void Second()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Second function. ServiceID: {0}", serviceID);
    }
}

class Server
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:8000"));
        NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IFirst), binding, "");
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ISecond), binding, "");
        host.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("Successfully opened port 8000.");
        Console.ReadLine();          
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

and client:

```
class Client
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ChannelFactory<IFirst> firstFactory = new ChannelFactory<IFirst>(new NetTcpBinding(), new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:8000"));
        IFirst iForst = firstFactory.CreateChannel();
        iForst.First();

        ChannelFactory<ISecond> secondFactory = new ChannelFactory<ISecond>(new NetTcpBinding(), new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:8000"));
        ISecond iSecond = secondFactory.CreateChannel();
        iSecond.Second();

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

When I run it I get output:

```
Successfully opened port 8000.
Service 1 created.
First function. ServiceID: 1
Service 2 created.
Second function. ServiceID: 2
```

In my case server creates two instances of Service. What I want to do is call Second function for the same Service instance that First did.

Answer (score 2):

You can do two things:

Move Second to IFirst so

```
public interface IFirst
{
    [OperationContract]
    void First();

    [OperationContract]
    void Second();
}
```

Or use a Singleton for the service instance

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)] 
class Service : IFirst, ISecond
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your behaviour to single

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
```

As you are using `InstanceContextMode.PerSession` that means service creates `a session` for each `client` as You are trying to connect to service from two clients thats why it is creating two instances of Service

by changing it to `InstanceContextMode.Single` only one instance of Service will serve both of your clients.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.instancecontextmode.aspx)

> The System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext **manages the association
>   between the channel and the user-defined service objects**. Use the
>   InstanceContextMode enumeration with the
>   ServiceBehaviorAttribute.InstanceContextMode property to specify the
>   lifetime of the InstanceContext object. can create a new
>   InstanceContext object for every call, every session or specify that
>   the InstanceContext object is bound to a single service object. 
>        **The Single value specifies that a single InstanceContext object should be used for the lifetime of the service.**

Answer (score 0):

I know the post is old, but for others.

What you can do is combine your IFirst and ISecond into ICombinedService.
Then you would create a single channel in your client - meaning a single instance of your service host session would be created.

In your current code you are creating a connection for IFirst, and ISecond [These are the two session instances you created.]

IFirst iForst = firstFactory.CreateChannel(); // First Session Created!

ISecond iSecond = secondFactory.CreateChannel(); // Second Session Created!

To change that behavior you will need to combine the services into one service; and can make per session calls on that.

```
class Client
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ChannelFactory<ICombinedFirstSecond> combinedFactory = new ChannelFactory<ICombinedFirstSecond>(new NetTcpBinding(), new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:8000"));
        ICombinedFirstSecond iCombinedFirstSecond = combinedFactory.CreateChannel();
        iCombinedFirstSecond.First();
        iCombinedFirstSecond.Second();

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

This is what I think you really are looking for and not a singleton service.