# WCF how to create two channels connected to the same service instance

Tags: c#, wcf, channel

I have some problems with WCF service instances.

```
ChannelFactory<IMyInterface> factory = new ChannelFactory<IMyInterface>(new NetTcpBinding(), new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:8000"));

IMyInterface iFirst = firstFactory.CreateChannel();
iFirst.firstMethod();

IMyInterface iSecond = firstFactory.CreateChannel();
iSecond.secondMethod();
```

It works fine but creates two instances of service class on server side.
`InstanceContextMode` is set to `InstanceContextMode.PerSession` and I would like to keep it that way. I found this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx#S4

In section `Duplicating a Proxy` is Figure 5 Duplicating a Proxy. I seems to be perfect solution but `IClientChannel` no longer contains `ResolveInstance()` method. Is there any other way to create two channels connected to one service instance without setting `InstanceContextMode` to `InstanceContextMode.Single`?

Comment: May be you want to finish your first question posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504059/wcf-multiple-channels-for-one-serivce-instance

Answer (score 1):

The IClientChannel.ResolveInstance method has been replaced with a new extensibility point, the System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.IInstanceContextProvider interface.

The change is described here:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mahjayar/archive/2006/07/08/660176.aspx - perhaps you can implement that interface to get what you want to acheive.